# Merge two formulas in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

This formula gives me the name of an author but the order is 'Last name Name'
`=IMPORTXML("http://www.libraccio.it/libro/"& L2 & "/ricerca.html","//a[@id='autore']")`

This one switches the order so it becomes 'Name Last Name'

```
=RIGHT(L2, LEN(L2)- FIND(" ",L2))&" "& LEFT(L2, FIND(" ",L2)-1)
```

but it's a two-step process. How can I merge them together in one formula?

`=importXML("http://www.libraccio.it/libro/"& L2 & "/ricerca.html","//a[@id='autore']") and =RIGHT(L2, LEN(L2)- FIND(" ",L2))&" "& LEFT(L2, FIND(" ",L2)-1)` is not correct.

Comment: @pnuts What's wrong with it? I edited the title if it's better this way.

Comment: @pnuts Oh, I see what you mean now! I'm using google spreadsheets but I put excel too because the formulas and the syntax are the same (in my experience, at least).

Comment: Your question includes the IMPORTXML function which is not found in Excel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace each instance of L2 in the second formula with your first formula:

`=RIGHT(IMPORTXML("http://www.libraccio.it/libro/"& L2 & "/ricerca.html","//a[@id='autore']"), LEN(L2)- FIND(" ",IMPORTXML("http://www.libraccio.it/libro/"& L2 & "/ricerca.html","//a[@id='autore']")))&" "& LEFT(IMPORTXML("http://www.libraccio.it/libro/"& L2 & "/ricerca.html","//a[@id='autore']"), FIND(" ",IMPORTXML("http://www.libraccio.it/libro/"& L2 & "/ricerca.html","//a[@id='autore']"))-1)`

This is of course very long. Here's a better way in Excel: use a named formula to store the name (FYI you can also do this in Google Sheets).

Press `Ctrl+F3->New` and enter `AuthorLastFirst` in the `Name:` field and

`=IMPORTXML("http://www.libraccio.it/libro/"& $L$2 & "/ricerca.html","//a[@id='autore']")`

in the `Refers to:` field. Now you can simply do:

`=RIGHT(AuthorLastFirst, LEN(L2)- FIND(" ",AuthorLastFirst))&" "& LEFT(AuthorLastFirst, FIND(" ",AuthorLastFirst)-1)`

Comment: Keep in mind that `IMPORTXML` is not a valid Excel formula, although it is a valid formula in Google Sheets. Your question, however, assumed `IMPORTXML` was working for you in Excel, so I was assuming you are using a user-defined formula of some sort.

Comment: Again, I was assuming the method in the question was working as given. If the information needed for each formula is different, the question as asked doesn't make sense because both formulas refer to `L2` even though both formulas require different inputs. If they both require different inputs, they can't refer to the same cell.

Comment: FYI: you should be able to get this working in Google Sheets just fine (well, apart from the `L2` problem). The process of creating named formulas is different than above, however.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear for others, this will only work in Google Sheets (due to both the IMPORTXML and REGEXREPLACE functions, which are not natively supported in Excel):

`=REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("http://www.libraccio.it/libro/"&L2& "/ricerca.html","//a[@id='autore']"),"^(.+) (.+)$","$2 $1")`